# Elasticsearch sort not working on nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Elasticsearch sort not working on nested field. It's showing mixed of ascending and descending values. Like 40, 30, 50 . It's not showing in ascending order like this: 30, 40, 50

Query:

```
"sort": [
    {
      "sellerInfoES.offerPrice": {
        "order": "asc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true,
        "missing": "_last"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please show the data which causes the unexpected result in your post as well.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting on a nested field is hard, the problem is that you can have multiple nested docs so you have to decide which document to pick. One way is to have the minimum value of a certain field in the nested docs and sort on that value. You can do this using the **mode** property. You also need the **nested_path** property.

It should be something like this:

```
   "sort" : [
       {
          "sellerInfoES.offerPrice" : {
             "mode" :  "avg",
             "order" : "asc",
             "nested_path" : "sellerInfoES"
          }
       }
    ]
```

More info can be found in the elasticsearch reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_nested_sorting_example